# cordova build for armhf architecture failed: overlayfs mount error

Tags: ubuntu-touch, arm

my goal is to build html5 app for armhf architecture (Raspbian,debian) devices like Raspberry Pi and armhf architecture based linux OS.

I have installed cordova on Ubuntu-16.04 which I have in my windows VMWare workstation with reference to this (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ubuntu/).

When I build app for device (cordova -d build --device -- --verbose), I ran into following error:

```
user001@ubuntu:~/Documents/myproject$ cordova -d build --device -- --verbose
No scripts found for hook "before_build".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json modification.
Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating config.xml with most current list of platforms.
Failed to require PlatformApi instance for platform "ubuntu". Using polyfill instead.
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in ubuntu platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in ubuntu platform. Continuing...
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "ubuntu"
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
Running command: /home/user001/Documents/myproject/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build --device --verbose
Building Phone Application...
cp -Rf /home/user001/Documents/myproject/www/img/logo.png /home/user001/Documents/myproject/platforms/ubuntu/www
E: 10mount: mount: unknown filesystem type 'overlayfs'
E: 15binfmt: update-binfmts: unable to open /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf-7d5175c0-d77c-4493-b5d4-89eba366df9c/bin/sh: No such file or directory
E: click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf-7d5175c0-d77c-4493-b5d4-89eba366df9c: Chroot setup failed: stage=setup-start
Command returned 1: schroot -c click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf -- env DEB_TARGET_ARCH_OS=linux DEB_TARGET_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnueabihf DEB_BUILD_ARCH=amd64 DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE=arm-linux-gnueabihf DEB_HOST_ARCH=armhf DEB_HOST_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnueabihf DEB_TARGET_ARCH_BITS=32 DEB_TARGET_GNU_TYPE=arm-linux-gnueabihf DEB_TARGET_GNU_CPU=arm DEB_BUILD_MULTIARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu DEB_HOST_ARCH_OS=linux DEB_TARGET_ARCH=armhf DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE=x86_64-linux-gnu DEB_HOST_ARCH_ENDIAN=little DEB_HOST_ARCH_BITS=32 DEB_BUILD_ARCH_BITS=64 DEB_HOST_GNU_CPU=arm DEB_BUILD_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnu DEB_BUILD_ARCH_OS=linux DEB_TARGET_ARCH_ENDIAN=little DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH=arm-linux-gnueabihf DEB_BUILD_GNU_CPU=x86_64 DEB_HOST_ARCH_CPU=arm DEB_BUILD_ARCH_ENDIAN=little DEB_TARGET_ARCH_CPU=arm DEB_BUILD_ARCH_CPU=amd64 DEB_TARGET_MULTIARCH=arm-linux-gnueabihf echo 1

Error: missing armhf chroot
run:
sudo click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-sdk-15.04 create
Command finished with error code 0: /home/user001/Documents/myproject/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build --device,--verbose
No scripts found for hook "after_compile".
No scripts found for hook "after_build".
user001@ubuntu:~/Documents/myproject$ sudo click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-sdk-15.04 create
[sudo] password for user001: 
A chroot for that name and architecture already exists.
Please see the man-page how to use it.
```

Can anyone please help me out to fix this issue? Here are some information:

```
user001@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
user001@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.12.0-041200-generic #201707022031 SMP Mon Jul 3 00:32:52 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
user001@ubuntu:~$ cordova -v
7.0.1
user001@ubuntu:~$ node -v
v4.2.6
user001@ubuntu:~$ npm -v
3.5.2
user001@ubuntu:~$
```