# HTML app to deb package - for Raspberry, BeagleBone device

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, arm, debuild

I have simple html,css,js file based application. I want to convert it into .deb package which should be compatible to install on Raspberry Pi Zero (Raspbian - 9.1 - stretch), Beagle Bone device (Debian - 7.11 - wheezy).

I used [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) to create package for Android, Windows Mobile which works fine. Using cordova I have an option to build package for Ubuntu, but when I try to build the same for target arm architecture devices (Raspberry Pi, Beagle Bone) I get some errors, refer to this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964231/cordova-build-for-armhf-architecture-failed-overlayfs-mount-error).

Is there any tools or methods available to create .deb package from html source files?

Comment: Have you checked 
https://electron.atom.io/
& 
nwjs.io

Comment: I didn't looked at it, I will give it a try, thanks

Comment: Let me know, then I can post it as an answer :) Good luck

Comment: Hi, I'm able to create package using electron and the installation also successful. But when I launch application I get no response in Debian and "Invalid desktop entry file:'/usr/share/applications/myapp.desktop'" error in Raspbian.

Comment: have you checked this? https://github.com/unindented/electron-installer-debian/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I checked and created package as instructed in that post

Comment: and was it successful?

Comment: It was successful and I installed the deb package on device which was also successful. After that I get error when launching the application.

Comment: can post the error you get?

Comment: A dialog box prompts "Invalid desktop entry file:'/usr/share/applications/myapp.desktop'" as I stated earlier.

Comment: can you post the content of myapp.desktop above in the original question?

Comment: I found that I made a mistake when creating package using electron-packager. Now, the package creation and installation was successful, also I'm able to launch the application without error. Thank you for the valuable input.

Comment: Great to hear that :) 
I will post my reply as an answer. Would you accept that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options for doing that.

1. [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/)
2. [Node-Webkit](https://nwjs.io/)

Both support making install-able applications (.deb packages) from HTML, CSS and JS web application for Debian based Linux distributions operating systems.

Comment: I used electron to build .deb package. It supports package creation for [these] (https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager#supported-platforms) _Linux (for x86, x86_64, armv7l, and arm64 architectures)_ platforms. My beagle bone device uses armv7l/armhf and the package works well. But Raspberry Pi zero uses armv6l/armhf and it doesn't works in RPi zero. We planned to use RPi 2/3 to make it work